# Backup of Akonadi: What makes sense?

Tags: kde, akonadi

At https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Datensicherung/#4-was-zu-sichern-sich-nicht-lohnt (in German unfortunately) it says that it does not pay off to backup `~/.local/share/akonadi`. Why is that? What should I backup instead for Akonadi?

Answer (score 0):

See the 1st line in that paragraph:

> Es gibt einige Verzeichnisse, bei denen sich eine Sicherung nicht lohnt, weil ihr Inhalt nur vorübergehend benötigt wird (Cache) oder schnell wieder erstellt werden kann (Thumbnails)

- it is a cache ("Zwischenspeicher"). So it is not actual user data.

> What should I backup instead for Akonadi?

- `~/.local/share/contacts` for the contacts
- `~/.config/akonadi` holds the config files

If you want to move from 1 system to another you can copy `~/.local/share/akonadi` over to the other system. But as stated: this is a "cache" so it changes quickly and is restored when you use Akonadi.

Comment: However: There is information stored in Akonadi, that is not stored in the original resources, in my case maildir folder. Isn't that stored in `~/.local/share/akonadi`? And what makes `~/.local/share/contacts` different, why should *this* one be stored? (Please update your answer if possible.)

Comment: Akonadi uses the regular items in your system (and it uses the contacts stored in ~/.local/share/contacts to create its own cache). "maildir folder" not sure but that should be a config setting. I'd expect that to be in `~/.config/akonadi`; so part of the 2nd item to backup.

Comment: Ah, `~/.local/share/contacts` is just a resource - forgot that. Anyway, I'll give an example: When I add tags to contacts in Kontact, they are *not* stored in the resources. In the resources there is only a cryptic tag-identifier (look into a contact file with kate instead of KAdressbook), but the actual tag I set is *only* stored in Akonadi. I'd like to backup things like that.